# Conformal mapping of region between 4 circles

Tags: conformal-geometry

I want to solve the Laplace equation with drichlet boundary condition on 4 circles with radius $a$ in 2d plane. Circles are located at $x=r=0$, $x=y=A$, $x=A,y=0$ and $y=B, x=0$ and they do not overlap. I'm wondering if there is a way to do a conformal mapping for this system to make it easier to solve the Laplace equation. In the case of two circles, I know that it is possible to map the system to two concentric circles. Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Poorly phrased, we don't even know if the circles overlap. And what is "the system" that you map ?

Comment: I'm editing it @YvesDaoust

Comment: Is it fine now? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Are you serious ? You changed two words.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with your conformal mapping?

Comment: I want to solve the Laplace equation between these 4 circles and I want to do the conformal mapping to get an easier geometry in which I can solve the Laplace equation @Sten

Comment: A conformal mapping is just one which locally preserves angles. So your question is really unclear. If you know something about the geometry (before and after the mapping), you could start by drawing a sketch, both for your sake and for ours

Comment: Is it fine now? @YvesDaoust

Comment: I tried to improve the question @Sten

Comment: Are you serious ? You changed two words.